# how to patch the kernel from a repo

Tags: usb, kernel, patch

I would like to patch my kernel so that it would do zerocopy. I found this nice repo on github but i'm not too sure how to go about doing it.

https://github.com/Basler/linux-usb-zerocopy

it says on the wiki that only drivers/usb/core/devio.c needs to be modified. To patch the kernel, do i simply overwrite the original with the new drivers/usb/core/devio.c and build a new kernel?

Edit:
I found https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel which tells me how to build my own kernel. However, it's unclear how i can merge this with my current system (ubuntu 14.04). I was able to find my kernel source directory at `/usr/src` and I was able to find `drivers/usb/core` directory. However, i wasn't able to find `devio.c`. Only files I found were `Kconfig` and `Makefile`. I'm not sure how to go about copying `devio.c` from the repo and building the kernel again.

Comment: Is there a .patch file anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the GitHub repo, it seemed it is the kernel source. If only that file is modified, copy that file into the **source** and recompile.

Comment: So it seems like the linux source codes are located in `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.10.67-g458d45c` but when i go to `driver/usb/core/` , i don't see `devio.c` . I only see `Kconfig` and `Makefile`. My questions are 1. do i simply copy that file to `driver/usb/core/`  and 2. build it by `fakeroot debian/rules clean` and 
`fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to patch an Ubuntu kernel (since this is askubuntu.com).
You can easily patch your kernel by following this wiki:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel

To take a patch from another Linux repo you should find the differences that repo and the Ubuntu one and merge those changes. Since both are maintained in `git` you can use merging or cherry-picking to accomplish this.

So in summary:

1. Download sources to Ubuntu kernel repo
2. Merge changes
3. Build and install new kernel package

Comment: yes, i do want to patch ubuntu 14.04, but the repo doens't seem to be ubuntu. the repo says it only modified drivers/usb/core/devio.c which makes me wonder if i could simply copy that to ubuntu and try building the kernel